What does it mean when newey-west standard errors are much larger than other types of standard errors
I am doing a regression using time series data and when I use newey-west standard errors they are 3-4 times as large as other types of standard errors (heteroskedasticity-robust and different clustering). Why is this the case and can it tell me something? Thank you.

Consider the simple(st) case of a regression on a constant,
$$
Y_t=\mu+u_t\qquad t=1,\ldots,n,
$$
with $u_t\sim(0,\sigma^2)$.
Then, the conventional asymptotic variance estimate estimates $\sigma^2(X'X/n)^{-1}=\sigma^2=:\gamma_0$, as $X'X/n=1$. A HAC-type estimator such as Newey-West however estimates the long-run variance, that also includes the autocovariances $\gamma_j$ of $u_t$. Concretely,
$$lrv=\gamma_0+2\sum_{j=1}^\infty\gamma_j$$
In the AR(1) example $u_t=\phi u_{t-1}+\epsilon_t$ below, we know that
$$\gamma_j=\frac{\sigma^2_\epsilon\phi^j}{1-\phi^2},
$$
so that
$$
\begin{eqnarray*}
lrv&=&\frac{\sigma^2_\epsilon}{1-\phi^2}+2\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{\sigma^2_\epsilon\phi^j}{1-\phi^2}\\
&=&2\sum_{j=0}^\infty\frac{\sigma^2_\epsilon\phi^j}{1-\phi^2}-\frac{\sigma^2_\epsilon}{1-\phi^2}\\
&=&2\frac{\sigma^2_\epsilon}{(1-\phi^2)(1-\phi)}-\frac{\sigma^2_\epsilon}{1-\phi^2}\\
&=&\frac{2\sigma^2_\epsilon-(1-\phi)\sigma^2_\epsilon}{(1-\phi^2)(1-\phi)}\\
&=&\frac{\sigma^2_\epsilon(1+\phi)}{(1-\phi)(1+\phi)(1-\phi)}\\
&=&\frac{\sigma^2_\epsilon}{(1-\phi)^2}
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
Here, the ratio is
$$
\frac{lrv}{\gamma_0}=\frac{1-\phi^2}{(1-\phi)^2}=\frac{(1-\phi)(1+\phi)}{(1-\phi)^2}=\frac{1+\phi}{1-\phi}
$$
Hence, the when the AR(1) approaches the unit root region ($\phi\to1$) the ratio even diverges.
So when the HAC estimator is larger, this is likely due to (positive) serial correlation in $u_t$. The logic will be similar with clustered standard errors.
Illustration:
library(sandwich)
n <- 1e6
u <- arima.sim(list(ar=.8), n=n) # generate an AR(1) process for u with AR(1) coefficient .8
    
# set mu=0 and apply to u directly, so y=u
var(u) # close to theoretical variance of an AR(1), here 1/(1-.8^2)
n*lrvar(u, type="Newey-West", prewhite=F, adjust=F) # close to theoretical long-run variance of an AR(1), here 1/(1-.8)^2 

